# Get text on html element based on different one

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

So I have something like this

```
<tr>
  <td class="name">
     qwer
  </td>
  <td class="value">
     rtyu
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="name">
     asdf
  </td>
  <td class="value">
     zxcv
  </td>
</tr>
```

Looking for a method to get value element text (`zxcv`) if name element contains an entry of text (`asdf`)

Comment: did you try to write any code?

Answer (score 0):

You can you beautifulsoup, and create a list of all `<tr>` then iterate over each one and check if the text in `<td class="name">` is `asdf`, if true we then get the text inside `<td class="value">`.

In code:

```
import bs4 as bs

html= """<tr>
  <td class="name">
     qwer
  </td>
  <td class="value">
     rtyu
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="name">
     asdf
  </td>
  <td class="value">
     zxcv
  </td>
</tr>"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
trs = soup.findAll("tr")

for tr in trs:
    td_name=tr.find("td", {"class": "name"})
    if(td_name.text.strip() == "asdf"):
        td_value=tr.find("td", {"class": "value"})
        print(td_value.text.strip())
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like it, but do you have an answer for lxml's tree?